# Parabolic equations and nonconvex domains

Tags: convex-geometry, parabolic-pde

**Is there a (system of) parabolic equation(s) where qualitative properties depend on whether or not the (say, smooth and bounded) domain $\Omega$ is convex?** I am aware of a few cases where a *proof* requires convexity but that of course does not mean that there is a counterexample for the nonconvex setting.

For instance, positive solutions to the heat equation $u_t = \Delta u$ with homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions fulfil
$$\frac12 \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \int_\Omega \frac{|\nabla u|^2}{u} = -\int_\Omega u |D^2 \ln u|^2 + \int_{\partial \Omega} \partial_\nu |\nabla \sqrt u|^2$$
and the last term is nonpositive whenever $\Omega$ is convex while it can only be absorbed *up to an additive constant* by the dissipative term if $\Omega$ is nonconvex. (I hope I recall the details correctly.) That is, it seems like convexity could have an influence on the decay properties for $t \to \infty$ -- of course not for the heat equation but perhaps for some system of parabolic equation whose (only) energy functional includes a term such as $\int_\Omega \frac{|\nabla u|^2}{u}$?

Similarly, comparison arguments involving $|\nabla u|^2$ sometimes require convexity as only then one can guarantee $\partial_\nu |\nabla u|^2 \le 0$ on the boundary.

I am mainly interested in qualitative properties, less so in cases where some optimal constant gets worse in nonconvex settings.